# Zookeper GC rolling by date and size

Tags: java, garbage-collection, apache-zookeeper

Is it possible to roll Zookeper GC log by **date** and **size** (every day new log)?

I found how to roll only by size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not specific to zookeeper. Openjdk GC logs (or JVM logs in general with [unified logging](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/158)) only support rotation based on size.